# How can i add a image in jsp page from a Folder?

Tags: java, html, image, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have following directory of my project(in Eclipse)as below

```
WebContent
|
 --Image
   |
    --logo.jpg
 --WEB-INF
   |
   --web.xml
   --lib
 --index.jsp
 --WebPage
   |
    --sayan.jsp
```

I want to add logo.jpg in both index.jsp and sayan.jsp page.
I do this in the following method

for index.jsp,

```
<img src="/Image/logo.jpg" />
```

and for sayan.jsp,

```
<img src="../Image/logo.jpg" />
```

But in both case image does not appear in webpages.How can I load logo.jpg image in both pages?

Comment: How about `logo.jpg`?

Comment: It's in container so how you are thinking to display only logo.jpg.
Anyways image in Image folder so there is no use giving only filename

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try : `<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Image/logo.jpg" />`

Comment: If only `logo.jsp` existed